# what rong in i want two table data select with 2 condition

Tags: crystal-reports, report

my project in vb6.0 i want to show crystal report 4 with 2 access table. i want first field id and second exam_Date. both field are available in both table. i want pass selection formula from my code. Below is code-

```
Dim Y As Integer, m As Integer, d As Integer

Y = Year(DTPicker1.Value)

m = Month(DTPicker1.Value)

d = Day(DTPicker1.Value)
```

selection formula:

```
CrystalReport1.SelectionFormula = "{Master.ID} = '" + Text1.Text + "' and {Master.Exam_Date} =Date(" & Y & "," & m & "," & d & ") and {Path_PatientData.Exam_Date}=Date(" & Y & "," & m & "," & d & ")"

CrystalReport1.PrintReport
```

but don't show report.

Comment: have you checked whether data exists in table for the date you are viewing the report.

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience in CR as a standalone tool but by seeing your code I would like to suggest some changes.

1. you picking date from two tables in slelection formula that may be creating problem, so instead of that since both table are linked take the date from only one table.

something like this.

```
CrystalReport1.SelectionFormula = "{Master.ID} = '" + Text1.Text + "' and {Master.Exam_Date} >=Date(" & Y & "," & m & "," & d & ") and {Master.Exam_Date} <=Date(" & Y & "," & m & "," & d & ")
```

use if its helpful else discard.